# custom div panel css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Can I create a css panel just like the below bootstrap css script without using bootstrap library

```
<style type="text/css">

.panel-custom-horrible-red {
    border-color: #ff0000;
}
.panel-custom-horrible-red > .panel-heading {
    background: #ff0000; 
    color: #ffffff;
    border-color: #ff0000;
}
</style>
```

**html**

```
<div class="panels panels-custom-horrible-red">
   <div class="panels-heading">
      <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
   </div>
   <div class="panel-body">
      Panel content
    </div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to create a standalone css panel without bootrap library. Many Thanks

Comment: you are missing the last 's' in 'panel' in your css if that can help https://jsfiddle.net/eao4ohLt/

Answer (score 0):

How is this for a start.  The number after 'box' refers to how many you want to fit in a row, and you need to adjust the width of that box class in the css accordingly, 33% for 3, 25% for 4, etc.

```css
.box {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: pink;
}
.box2 {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 49.5%;
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
.clear-float {
  clear: both
}
```

```html
<div class='box'>
  <div class='box2'>
    contained box
  </div>
  <div class='box2'>
    contained box
  </div>
  <div class='box2'>
    contained box
  </div>
  <div class='clear-float'>
  </div>
</div>
```